# json nested array value parsing to object

Tags: json, parsing

json nested array value parsing. how to retrive the following json to a .obj values

```
> { "data": {
    "stuff": {
        "onetype": [
            { "id": 1, "name": "" },
            { "id": 2, "name": "" }
        ],
        "othertype": [
            { "id": 2, "xyz": [-2, 0, 2], "n": "Crab Nebula", "t": 0, "c": 0, "d": 5 }
        ]
    },
    "otherstuff": {
        "thing":
            [[1, 42], [2, 2]]
    }
}
}
```

Comment: can you make it clear? its little bit difficult to understand your problem .

Comment: This Json object looks ok.  What can be understood from your message is that you probably have some code to parse it with some library on some language, and it doesn't work.

Comment: @anu mol provide some more info if you need an answer i.e. what type result are you expecting? where you stuck and what you have applied? If possible share some code with us?